# How to convert PFObject to PFRelation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject, pfrelation

Here is my code in **Swift**

```
@IBAction func addUser(sender: AnyObject) {
    var query = PFUser.query()
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTextField)
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects:PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            var friendList = PFUser.currentUser().relationForKey("friends") // I  don't understand relationforKey, what does it do? and what happen inside ( )?

            var addFriend = objects
            if addFriend != nil {
                PFRelation.addObject(addFriend!) // <- error here
                println("added")
            }
            PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) in

                if error != nil {
                    println("Error")
                }
                else {
                    println("saved")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I want to let my app be able to add other users via their username with **Parse** and I have trouble with `PFRelation.addObject(addFriend!)`. It shows that I cannot add `PFObject` into this method since inside ( ) has to be `PFRelation` object but I don't know how to convert this.
Any helps is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you have the correct naming convention. Does `usernameTextField` is an instance of `UITextField` or `String`? Be careful for it.

For your question, your `PFRelation` does not know which objects to associate. How can it relate using `addObject` then? Also, you can not directly call `addObject` using `PFRelation` because `addObject` is not a factory method.

Here is something that you need to do, I just type it here and it might have errors:

```
let currentUser = PFUser().currentUser()
let relation = currentUser.relationForKey("friend") // assume that name of your relation column is friend
relation.addObject(objects) // please be careful for your naming convention. You should use object as a name here

// Then save using saveInBackgroundWithBlock
```